# why solution of $f''(x)+af'(x)+bf(x)=0$ is a vector space of dimension $2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathcal C^2(\mathbb R^2)$ and $$W=\{f\in V\mid f''+af'(x)+bf(x)=0\}.$$
I proved that $W$ is a subspace of $V$, but how can I prove that it has dimension $2$ ?

Comment: Are you sure it is $C^2(\mathbb R^2)$ and not $C^2(\mathbb R)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Let $u,v$ be any two solutions. Define 
$$W(t):= u'v-uv'$$

Then 
$$W'=u''v+u'v'-u'v'-uv''=(-au'-bu)v-u(-av'-bv)=-au'v+auv'=-aW$$

Solving this separable ODE you get $W(t)=Ce^{-at}$ for some $C$.

Now, pick any three solutions $u,v,w$. By the above, there exists some constants $C_1,C_2$ such that 
$$u'v-uv'=C_1 e^{-at} \\
u'w-uw'= C_2e^{-at}$$

If $C_1=C_2=0$ then $u'v=uv'$ and $u'w=uw'$ are separable ODE which are easy to solve.

Otherwise
$$C_2(u'v-uv')=C_1(u'w-uw')\\
C_2\frac{u'v-uv'}{u^2}=C_1\frac{u'w-uw'}{u^2}\\
-C_2 \left( \frac{v}{u} \right)'=-C_1 \left( \frac{w}{u} \right)' \\
C_2 \frac{v}{u}=C_1 \frac{w}{u}+C_3 \\
C_2v=C_1w+C_3u
$$

Answer (score 2):

Sketch: If you assume it to be known (from ODE theory) that the solution of the initial value problem is unique, then every solution is determined by the initial values $f(0)=c_1$ and $f'(0)=c_2$, and is in fact equal to $c_1 g_1 + c_2 g_2$, where $g_1$ is determined by the initial values $g_1(0)=1$ and $g_1'(0)=0$, and the other way around for $g_2$.

Comment: Is it possible to prove that ?

Comment: Isn't the fact that any solution to the IVP unique usually deduced from the fact that this space is 2 dimensional?

Comment: @user657324: Prove what? The existence and uniqueness follows from the Picard–Lindelöf theorem, if you write the equation as a system of two first-order ODEs by letting $x_1=f$, $x_2=f'$. Proving the other claim (as well as linear independence of $g_1$ and $g_2$) is not more than a rather straightforward exercise.